# C _ Summing function not giving desired result

Tags: c

I have been working on this program and I got to a roadblock. I got everything done but one detail is not working right upon compiling.

> You are to write a program that reads characters from the keyboard
>   using the getch() function. All lower case letters will be converted
>   to upper case and printed out to the display using the putchar()
>   function. All uppercase letters will be printed using putchar(). All
>   individual digits will be accumulated and the sum will be printed at
>   the end of the program using printf(). You will write your own
>   function to return the upper case of the letter, do not use the C
>   library conversion functions, and a second function which receives the
>   current sum using the current character digit, do not use the C
>   library conversion functions. The convert digit function will convert
>   the character digit to a decimal value and accumulate the digit to the
>   sum returning the new sum. Only the letters will be printed out
>   nothing else. The program will continue until the return is received
>   at which time the sum of the digits will be printed on the next line.
>   What was entered: a9 wF23’;/4i What the line actually shows: aAwWFiI
>   The sum of the digits is: 18

I posted what I already worked on below. The porgram does everything except for the part where it needs to sum integers (which were originally characters but were converted). It gives me a very large number, much larger than the sum of 
the entered digits.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ctrlz 26

char cvttoupper(char);
int cvtdigit(int, char);

int main ()
{
    int sum, d;
    char c, cupper;
    sum = 0;
    do  
    {   
        c = getch();

        if (c>='A' && c<='Z' || c>='a' && c<='z' )
        {   
            putch(c);
            if(c>='a' && c<='z')
            {   
                cupper = cvttoupper(c);
                putch(cvttoupper(c));                                       
            }   
        }   
        if (c>='0' && c<='9')
        {   
            d=c&0x0F;             
            sum = cvtdigit(sum,c);                      
        }   
    }   while (c != ctrlz);

    printf("\nThe sum of the digits is: %d\n", sum);

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

char cvttoupper(char c)
{
    char cupper;
    cupper= c & 0x5F;
    return (cupper);
}

int cvtdigit(int d, char c)
{
    int sum;
    sum=sum+d;
    return (sum);        
}
```

Would appreciate any feedback on how to make the summing part work right. I suspect it is the way the arguments are listed with every function that is not right. (I had to create the functions yself, could not use C library functions).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try and wrangle this indentation under control?

Comment: `sum = cvtdigit(sum,c);`? `sum = cvtdigit(sum,d);`? Typo in last parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your sum function:

```
int cvtdigit(int d, char c)
{
    int sum;
    sum=sum+d;
    return (sum);        
}
```

The original `sum` from `main` is stored in `d`.  What you end up doing is creating a new variable named `num` that is not initialized, adding the value of `d` (i.e. `sum` in `main`) to the uninitialized `sum` and returning that value.  That's why you're getting strange numbers.

Change the function to remove `sum` and add the value of `d` (which you should rename to `sum`) and `c`, first subtracting `'0'` i.e. the character code for the character 0 from `c` so you get a value from 0 to 9.

```
int cvtdigit(int sum, char c)
{
    sum=sum+(c-'0');
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why, when substracting '0', we get the actual digit value? It does functionally work but I am not sure why.

Comment: @legallyalienated The encoding values for the characters '0' to '9' are guaranteed to be consecutive.  So '0' - '0' is 0, '1' - '0' is 1, '2' - '0' is 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the old `sum` to `cvtdigit`, you should add to that, not use an uninitialized local variable.

You get the numeric value of a digit by subtracting `'0'` from it.

```
int cvtdigit(int sum, char c)
{
    int d = c - '0';
    sum += d;
    return sum;        
}
```